# F# multiplication table function

Tags: sorting, math, f#

I'm sitting with this assignment that requests the following:

The output needs to be formatted like this:

[image: correct format]

Comment: Can you share the code that you wrote so far?

Answer (score 1):

You said that you wrote a solution using loops, but are not happy with it. I will not give a solution to an assignment (which is not what StackOverflow is for), but there is a more general question that can be answered here.

First of all, there is nothing bad with imperative F# code - that can sometimes be useful. However, you can typically rewrite imperative solution based on loops using recursion. Here is a minimal imperative function:

```
let demo () = 
  let mutable res = "0"
  for i in 1 .. 10 do 
    res <- res + "," + string i
  res
```

The same thing can be done using recursion by making `i` into a function parameter:

```
let demo () =
  let rec inner i = 
    if i > 10 then ""
    else "," + string i + inner (i + 1)
  "0" + inner 1
```

This should give you a hint about how to solve your original problem using an alternative recursive implementation.

Comment: i added a picture of what the output needs to look like , and im not sure how to do it with the first demo code without recursion.